# HTML5 URL update without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to use the HTML5 window.history.pushState function, but i can't quite get it working.

This is the function:

```
    function changeUrl() {
        window.history.pushState(object, "Title", "?side=annoncer&sletid=1");
    }
```

And this is the link which should invoke it:

```
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="changeUrl();">
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to set an object

```
function changeUrl() {
        window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "?side=annoncer&sletid=1");
    }
```

check it and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
         window.history.pushState(null, "Title", "?side=annoncer&sletid=1");
```